# Unable to click on "Tab"

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

While clicking on "Tab" getting following exception.

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Element is not clickable at point (160.5, 7.5). Other element would receive the click: 
>   Command duration or timeout: 71 milliseconds
>   Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 16:57:40'
>   System info: host: 'Saba-Aziz', ip: '10.20.30.44', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_91'
>   Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
>   Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=true, rotatable=false, handlesAlerts=true, databaseEnabled=true, version=46.0.1, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=false, acceptSslCerts=true, webStorageEnabled=true, locationContextEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
>   Session ID: 5d2ead97-c71c-4a86-9ffb-3e7bbb174503
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:327)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:85)
>       at WorldBankDatacls.main(WorldBankDatacls.java:56)

I have used web driver's findElement methods like XPath, Id,..etc. but no luck! Please anyone help me!

Comment: Share your code and website please. :-)

Comment: you should try JavascriptExecutor to perform click..

Comment: @SaurabhGaur Thanks.  It works with JavascriptExecuter!

Answer (score 1):

Here you can perform click by using `JavascriptExecutor`as follows :-

```
WebElement el = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("here is your xpath"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)webDriver
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", el);
```

Answer (score 0):

Some element which is on the top recieves click instead your tab. You should make screenshot after your click to see what is happening.